# Find max and min DateTime in Linq group

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, entity-framework

I'm trying to find the max and min `DateTime`s from a CSV import.

I have this to import the data from the temp `DataTable`:

```
var tsHead = from h in dt.AsEnumerable()
         select new
                    {
                        Index = h.Field<string>("INDEX"),
                        TimeSheetCategory = h.Field<string>("FN"),
                        Date = DdateConvert(h.Field<string>("Date")),
                        EmployeeNo = h.Field<string>("EMPLOYEE"),
                        Factory = h.Field<string>("FACTORY"),
                        StartTime = DdateConvert(h.Field<string>("START_TIME")), //min
                        FinishTime = DdateConvert(h.Field<string>("FINISH_TIME")), //max
                    };
```

Which works fine. I then want to group the data and show the Start time and finish time which is the min / max of the respective fields.

So far I have this:

```
var tsHeadg = from h in tsHead
                      group h by h.Index into g //Pull out the unique indexes
                      let f = g.FirstOrDefault() where f != null
                      select new
                                 {
                                     f.Index,
                                     f.TimeSheetCategory,
                                     f.Date,
                                     f.EmployeeNo,
                                     f.Factory,
                                     g.Min(c => c).StartTime, //Min starttime should be timesheet start time
                                     g.Max(c => c).FinishTime, //Max finishtime should be timesheet finish time
                                 };
```

With the thinking that `g.Min` and `g.Max` would give me the lowest and highest `DateTime` for each timesheet (grouped by index)

This doesn't work however...  Whats the best way of finding the highest and lowest value of DateTimes within a group?

Comment: Note that `g.Min(c => c)` means find the minimum of the whole object instance of the anonymous type in your first query.  There is no natural ordering defined for this type, so there's no meaning to finding `.Min` or `.Max`.  Did you perhaps mean `g.Min(c => c.StartTime)`?

Comment: @mellamokb I did, which p.s.w.g pointed out lower and solved my problem

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try using this

```
var tsHeadg = 
    (from h in tsHead
     group h by h.Index into g //Pull out the unique indexes
     let f = g.FirstOrDefault() 
     where f != null
     select new
     {
         f.Index,
         f.TimeSheetCategory,
         f.Date,
         f.EmployeeNo,
         f.Factory,
         MinDate = g.Min(c => c.StartTime),
         MaxDate = g.Max(c => c.FinishTime),
     });
```